# godot 4 with different input code for a player and a car

Tags: input, key-bindings, godot4

I have a 3d godot project and in it I have a player and a car. Sometimes that player goes into the car. When the player is outside the car the keyboard and key bindings should work for the player. When in the car they should control the car. Currently the player works fine, but when I go in the car the car does not move. I'm totally confused. I don't even know what code to show you. First the player. This is not all of the _physics_process function, just the first part. You can see I have this set of Input.get_action_strength methods commented out.

```
    func _physics_process(delta):
        #get keyboard input
        direction = Vector3.ZERO
        var h_rot = global_transform.basis.get_euler().y
        
        #f_input = Input.get_action_strength("move_backward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")
        #h_input = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
        
        if Global.player_status != Global.STATUS_CAR:   
            f_input = Physics.f_input()
            h_input = Physics.h_input()

        direction = Vector3(h_input, 0, f_input).rotated(Vector3.UP, h_rot).normalized()
```

Then the car. Again, this is not all of the _physics_process code.

```
    func _physics_process(delta):
        if Global.player_status == Global.STATUS_CAR:
            
            player_walk.position = Vector3(position)
            
            var f_input : float = float(Physics.f_input() + 0) / 1.0 
            var h_input : float = float(Physics.h_input() + 0) / 1.0 
            
            print( f_input, ' ' , h_input, ' ' , position, ' car')
            #var direction = player_walk.direction  
            steer = lerp(float(steer), float(h_input * 0.4), 5 * delta)         
            #steer = lerp(float(steer), float(Input.get_axis("move_right", "move_left") * 0.4), 5 * delta)
            steering = steer
```

Then I have a Autoload that is called Physics.

```
    extends Node3D 

    func f_input():
        if Global.player_status == Global.STATUS_CAR:
            return Input.get_axis("move_backward", "move_forward")
        else: 
            return Input.get_action_strength("move_backward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")
        
    func h_input():
        if Global.player_status == Global.STATUS_CAR:
            return Input.get_axis("move_right", "move_left")
        else: 
            return Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
```

What should I be trying to do? I think with this setup the player moves fine but the car does not always get input from the keys.